# Python save numpy array set_printoptions

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image which I've read in with cv2 and python. - I think I'm going to 'store' the image as a nparray in my db for later processing, easy retrieval etc.

What's the difference between just

```
img = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
print(img)
```

and this:

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
print(img)
```

The latter being a much much larger array for some reason which I do not yet understand.

Comment: I also see theres a ```asarray``` which might be better to use here ?

Comment: How is `print` related to storing in a database? You are not thinking of storing it as a string, are you? You should store it as a blob (binary data). Python has `pickle` which is really good for that. You can also encode it as a PNG or JPEG in memory, and store that as a blob.

Comment: Anyway, in your second case, the full array is printed, by default NumPy only shows a small part of larger arrays.